# Schedule a web service using powershell

Tags: powershell, web-services

Very new to Powershell and google is not being my friend. I am hoping you can give me the simple answer I am to slow to find.

I am trying to set a script that will start  a web service at a set time (8am) and then stop it at close of day (8pm)
Google has many versions however I am unable to find any combination that works for me. Yes, I am "slow" when it comes to searching.

Many thanks

I have tried each of the following with no joy and some other combinations.

```
$service = $ABC.GetWebService("IEnvironmentService")
$serviceName = "ABC Interval JobExecutor Service"

$Time = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 13:33 -Once
Set-ScheduledTask -$serviceName -Trigger $Time
```

Gives an error - The system cannot find the file specified.

So, I tried

```
$service = $ABC.GetWebService("IEnvironmentService")
$serviceName = "ABC Interval JobExecutor Service"

$Time = New-ServiceTrigger -At 13:33 -Once
Set-ScheduledTask -$serviceName -Trigger $Time
```

Gives error - The term 'New-ServiceTrigger' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Comment: The code provided appears incomplete. What is `$ABC`?

Comment: Hi, $ABC is me blanking the company name, code that works is  below, I can schedlue this manually but want to run multiple by powershell runner.      $service = $**.GetWebService("IEnvironmentService")
$serviceName = "*** Interval JobExecutor Service"

$service.StopServiceByName($serviceName)

Comment: Right, but what type of object is stored in `$ABC`?

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: If I could I would, you'd think

Comment: I have faith that with the help of the linked information you could - though I see that Mathias has already done it for you. `New-ServiceTrigger` is indeed not a standard cmdlet. `-$serviceName` won't do what you want. `Set-ScheduledTask` needs an `-Action` argument, which you can create with `New-ScheduledTaskAction`.